# Use of readline()?

Tags: python

I have a question about this program:

```
%%file data.csv 
x1,x2,y
0.4946,5.7661,0
4.7206,5.7661,1
1.2888,5.3433,0
4.2898,5.3433,1
1.4293,4.5592,0
4.2286,4.5592,1
1.1921,5.8563,0
3.1454,5.8563,1

f = open('data.csv')
data = []
f.readline()
for line in f:
  (x1,x2,y) = line.split(',')
  x1 = float(x1)
  x2 = float(x2)
  y = int(y)
  data.append((x1,x2,y))
```

What is the purpose of readline here? I have seen different examples but here seems that it delete the first line.

Comment: That's about it, it simply skips the first line which doesn't contain any actual data.

Comment: first line is the header, explains the columns. It is not data, but semantics about them, i.e. metadata

Comment: The code should be using the `csv` module instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python is reading the data serially, so if a line gets read once, python jumps to the next one. The r.readline() reads the first line, so in the loop it doesn't get read.

Answer (score 3):

That's precisely the point: to delete the first line. If you notice, the file has the names of the columns as its first line (`x1,x2,y`), and the program wants to ignore that line.

Answer (score 1):

Using `readline()` method before reading lines of file in loop
is equals to:

```
for line in f.readlines()[1:]:     
    ...
```

for example that may be used to skip table header.

In your file, when you will convert `x1` variable to float type it raise `ValueError` because  in first iteration `x1` contain not digit sting type value `"x1"`. And to avoid that error you use `readline()` to swich iterator to second line wich contain pure digits.